# TSQL - Generating Quarter output

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns X, Date and Qtr as attached.

I need to get an output as mentioned in attachment (data taken only for 8 quarters)

[image]

```
create table mQtr
( X varchar(5), XDate  date, Qtr int);

insert into mQtr 
values ('X1', '2011-11-01', 4), ('X2', '2011-10-01', 4),
       ('X3', '2011-09-01', 3), ('X4', '2011-08-01', 3),
       ('X5', '2011-07-01', 3), ('X6', '2011-06-01', 2),
       ('X7','2011-05-01',2), ('X8','2011-04-01',2),
       ('X9','2011-03-01',1), ('X10','2011-02-01',1),
       ('X11','2011-01-01',1), ('X12','2010-12-01',4),
       ('X13','2010-11-01',4), ('X14','2010-10-01',4),
       ('X15','2010-09-01',3), ('X16','2010-08-01',3),
       ('X17','2010-07-01',3), ('X18','2010-06-01',2),
       ('X19','2010-05-01',2), ('X20','2010-04-01',2),
       ('X21','2010-03-01',1), ('X22','2010-02-01',1),
       ('X23','2010-01-01',1), ('X24','2009-12-01',4)
```

What I am expecting the following result set based on Qtr value, I would like to generate sum of X values. Output should be some like this:

```
Qtr     mOutput
----------------    
1       x1+x2
2       x3+x4+x5
3       x6+x7+x8
4       x9+x10+x11
5       x12+x13+x14
6       x15+x16+x17
7       x18+x19+x20
8       x21+x22+x23
```

Please help me to frame the query.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As more you elaborate your question it helps people to post more usefull answers. Also consider to write better and write down tables and expected results instead of posting images

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` with `HAVING count(*) = 3` in  statement. [This Link](http://www.sql-ex.com/help/select16.php) can be useful